# How to use IDN domain with swedish åäö when sharing on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, idn

I have a IDN domain "återvinnmera.se" and when I try to share the link i a post on Facebook, it fetches the image, title, description etc as it should, but the address that is shown is "xn--tervinnmera-w8a.se".

So my question is if there is anything I can do to make it show "återvinnmera.se" and not the IDN version? I have search a lot, but I can´t find a solution for it.
Since IDN domains have worked for so many years now, I though that Facebook would support and understand it by now?

Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is likely not a problem of “understanding” the IDN format, but a deliberate decision made to help fight fake news. IDN domains make it easy to try and fool users by using fake domains names that look very similar to the ones of established, trusted sources.

Comment: Ok thanks. But I still think it is strange that FB does´t support it fully.